# How to select first 2 items from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select the first 2 item from an array and also select just first name of each person from an object, not the full name.

These are my codes:

index.html

```
<body>
<button onclick="loadajax();">laod ajax</button>
<div id = "update"></div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

script.js

```
function loadajax(){
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    request.open('GET', 'data.json');
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((request.readyState===4) && (request.status===200)) {
            var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var output = '<ul>';
            for (var key in items) {
                output += '<li>his name is:' + items[key].name + ' with the id of:'+ items[key].id +'</li>';
            }
            output += '</ul>';
            document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = output;
        }
    }
    request.send();
}
```

data.json

```
[
  {
    "name":"Barot Bellingham",
    "id":"1"  
  },
  {
    "name":"alex benjan",
    "id":"2"  
  },
  {
    "name":"jony lekson",
    "id":"3"  
  }
]
```

this is the results:

- his name is:Barot Bellingham with the id of:1
- his name is:alex benjan with the id of:2
- his name is:jony lekson with the id of:3

but what I want is this:

- his name is:Barot  with the id of:1
- his name is:alex  with the id of:2

do you have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
for (let key in items.slice(0, 2)) { // ...etc
```

But in general it is advised not to use `for...in` on arrays. Use `for..of` (or `forEach`), in combination with destructuring and a template literal:

```
for (let {name, id} of items.slice(0, 2)) {
    output += `<li>his name is: ${name} with the id of: ${id}</li>`
}
```

Or, even better, use `map` in combination with `join`:

```
let output = '<ul>' + items.slice(0, 2).map(({name, id}) =>
    `<li>his name is: ${name} with the id of: ${id}</li>`
).join('') + '</ul>';
```

The first name can be extracted by taking the first word with `split` (this is not 100% correct, as some first names can consist of two or more words):

```
let output = '<ul>' + items.slice(0, 2).map(item =>
    `<li>his name is: ${item.name.split(' ')[0]} with the id of: ${id}</li>`
).join('') + '</ul>';
```

NB: This has little to do with Ajax or JSON, just with looping and array methods.

Comment: thanks, do you know how to select the first name instate of full name?

Comment: `items[key].name.split(' ')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach returning an array:

```
  var jsonArray = [
  {
    "name":"Barot Bellingham",
    "id":"1"  
  },
  {
    "name":"alex benjan",
    "id":"2"  
  },
  {
    "name":"jony lekson",
    "id":"3"  
  }
];

var user = jsonArray .map((user, index) => { 
        return { 'id': user.id, 'name' : user.name.split(' ')[0] }; 
 }).slice(0, 2)
```

output:
//`[{"id":"1","name":"Barot"},{"id":"2","name":"alex"}]`

Comment: It is confusing to call such a variable *json*, as JSON is a string format, not a JavaScript array.

Answer (score 0):

generally to get 2 first items from array:

```
 const items = [1, 2, 3]; 
 const [first, second] = items; // 1, 2
```

In your case it would be like this:

```
const [first, second] = items.map(({name, id}) => ({firstName: name.split(' ')[0], id}));
```

Comment: you should expand on this answer explain what you are doing in the example above.